# KDB: In-place delete from dictionary

Tags: dictionary, kdb

To upsert an element into the dictionary, I do

```
q) d[`x]:12345
```

This modifies existing dictionary and the operation cost is close to `O(1)` or `O(log N)` depending on the underlying implementation (hash table or tree) (I don't know in fact).

However, to remove a key I must use:

```
q) d:(enlist `x) _ d
```

Which is at least `O(N)` because it copies the full dictionary without deleting items in `O(N)` then assigns is to `d` in `O(1)` because of pointer.

This looks like delete operation discrimination! Maybe in-place delete is poorly documented but exists somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two more options include [apply](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/unclassified/#apply):

```
.[`d;();_;`x]
```

[functional delete](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/funsql/#delete)

```
![`d;();0b;enlist`x]
```

The last form is useful if you want to delete **multiple keys** in one go.  E.g.,

```
![`d;();0b;`x`y]
```

Comment: Thanks, any advise on how to implement multiple in-place delete of nested dictionary?  large[`a;`b]:3 ;    large[`a] _: `b / deletes only one, i need delete many

Comment: If your nested dictionary maps symbols to generic values, you should be able to use either the delete template or functional delete.  I'll update the answer to avoid the character limit in comments.

Comment: Did you try `![\`large.a;();0b;\`b\`c]`?

Answer (score 6):

Four forms support **deleting in place**.

[*Drop* through assignment](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#_-drop) allows you to drop a **single key** ‘in place’.

```
q)show d:`a`b`c`x!(1;2 3;4;5)
a| 1
b| 2 3
c| 4
x| 5
q)d _: `x
q)d
a| 1
b| 2 3
c| 4
```

[*Apply*](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/unclassified/#apply) will allow you to **parameterise the key**:

```
q)show d:`a`b`c`x!(1;2 3;4;5)
a| 1
b| 2 3
c| 4
x| 5
q).[`d;();_;`x]
q)d
a| 1
b| 2 3
c| 4
```

[`delete`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/qsql/#delete) like all Q-SQL templates similarly supports ‘in place’ through call-by-reference, and also allows you to drop **multiple keys**:

```
q)show d:`a`b`c`x!(1;2 3;4;5)
a| 1
b| 2 3
c| 4
x| 5
q)delete x,b from `d
`d
q)d
a| 1
c| 4
```

[Functional delete](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/funsql/#delete) supports **multiple keys** and allows you to **parameterise the keys**. (Use [`parse`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/parsetrees/#parse) to see the functional form of the Q-SQL template.)

```
q)show d:`a`b`c`x!(1;2 3;4;5)
a| 1
b| 2 3
c| 4
x| 5
q)parse "delete x,b from d"
!
`d
()
0b
,`x`b
q)![`d;();0b;`x`b]
`d
q)d
a| 1
c| 4
```

Links above are to the kdb+ documentation site [code.kx.com](http://code.kx.com/q).

Answer (score 5):

2 ways:

`` d _:`x ``

or

`` delete x from `d ``